# how can I change content in span after ajax success in MVC 4

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

```
<div>
  <span class="label">1</span>
  <a href="#" class="click">up</a>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.click').click(function(){
//$(this).parent().find('.label').html(2);
$.ajax({
    ....
    success: function(result){
    $(this).parent().find('.label').html(2);
    }
});
```

});

if i don't use ajax.post, value in  change.. and when i use, it doesn't change.

I don't know what happen? and how can i fix it.

Give me some advices please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` is not referring to your link (its inside the `$.ajax()` function). Assign the label element to a javascript variable before you make the ajax call so it can be accessed inside the ajax function.

```
$('.click').click(function(){
  var label = $(this).parent().find('.label');
  // or $(this).prev('.label');
  $.ajax({
    ....
    success: function(result){
      label.html(2);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. I got it.ư